# a datareader associeted with this command is already open, it must be closed first

Tags: c#

i have a tablelayoutpanel that contains a combobox with article names and 2 textboxs one for quantity and the other for displaying the finalprice of the article, i want to calculate the finalprice ( price * quantity ) but all i get is a exception "a datareader associeted with this command is already open, it must be closed first" but a closed all the readers :/

```
private void txtQ2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        try {
            int q = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow((TextBox)sender);
            ComboBox q1 = (ComboBox)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, q);
            String NameArt = q1.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select PriceArticle from tbl_article where NameArticle='" + NameArt + "'", sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr1.Read())
            {
                int x = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(q1);
                TextBox y1 = (TextBox)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, x);
                int z;
                bool parseOK1 = Int32.TryParse(y1.Text, out z);
                String a = dr1["PriceArticle"].ToString();
                int j;
                bool parseOK2 = Int32.TryParse(a, out j);
                int w = j * z;
                TextBox y2 = (TextBox)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(2, x);
                y2.Text = w.ToString();
            }
            dr1.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you keep a global connection object?. This is the source of your problems. Use a local connection, open  it, use it, close and dispose. No more data reader left open somewhere in your code.

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates: another operation is still open. Whatever the last query was: you didn't close it down cleanly. Note that the `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` objects are `IDisposable` so you should be `using` them. In the case of the code in the question:

```
using(var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select PriceArticle from tbl_article where NameArticle='" + NameArt + "'", sqlCon))
using(var dr1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
{
    // the rest of the code
}
```

It also goes almost without saying that you should never never concatenate input into SQL, and your SQL is hugely open to SQL Injection. Please please switch to parameters, or a tool that will help you get it right like "dapper". For example:

```
// via "dapper"
var article = sqlCon.QuerySingleOrDefault<string>(
    "select PriceArticle from tbl_article where NameArticle=@NameArt",
    new { NameArt });
if(article != null)
{
    ...
}
```